# MVC4 website only works on one PC, not other PC, fails with "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

The following MVC4 `ef-codefirst` application works fine on my computer, but nowhere else.

VS 2012 Ultimate and SQL Express is installed on both computers.

Both computers use this connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AppointmentMVC4-20130118154339;
Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AppointmentMVC4-20130118154339.mdf"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When trying to access the database from computers other than the development computer:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

The working machine has this DB connection:
[image]

Use of `localDB` or `sqlexpress` as connection does not matter; getting this to succeed matters.

`DbContext` class:

```
public class AppointmentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that LocalDB only supports local connections via named pipes protocol.
http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0004.htm

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this fixed it all.

```
<add name="AppointmentContext" connectionString="Data Source=
(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Appointments.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thank you Iraklis and jessehouwing for your help, great community.